# Swift JSON Data

Tags: json, swift

I received the JSON data as shown below, I want to get the "player_name" & "player_country" from this data. How do I get this?**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ4YE.png)

In case, the image does not load, please refer the below output:

```
["team_key": 2611, "team_name": Leicester, "team_badge": https://apiv2.apifootball.com/badges/2611_leicester.png, "players": <__NSArrayI 0x600003331e00>(
{
    "player_age" = 33;
    "player_country" = Denmark;
    "player_goals" = 0;
    "player_key" = 140150332;
    "player_match_played" = 30;
    "player_name" = "Schmeichel Kasper";
    "player_number" = 1;
    "player_red_cards" = 0;
    "player_type" = Goalkeepers;
    "player_yellow_cards" = 2;
},
{
    "player_age" = 23;
    "player_country" = England;
    "player_goals" = 3;
    "player_key" = 2242127097;
    "player_match_played" = 24;
    "player_name" = "Chilwell Benjamin";
    "player_number" = 3;
    "player_red_cards" = 0;
    "player_type" = Defenders;
    "player_yellow_cards" = 2;
},
{.....}
```

I tried the following to get required data from this:

```
var mainArray = [[String: Any]]()
var tryArray = [[String]]()

for i in jsonArray {
     if i["team_key"] as! String == teamID {
         self.mainArray.append(i)
     }
 }

 for i in self.mainArray {
     self.tryArray.append(i["player_name"] as! [String])
 }
```

I got this error with the above code:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I edited the post, please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Your “team_key” is an integer, but you are force casting it to a string, which probably causes the error. Do something like `if let teamKey = i[“team_key”] as? Int, teamKey == teamID`. This code assumes that your teamID is an int. If it is a string, use `String(teamKey)` to make it into a String.

Comment: I agree with @Jorn. Moreover the json has got a lot of error indeed check the json and its property type.

Comment: @Jorn Thanks for your answer, but the comparison of "team_key and teamID" is working fine. Next codes are giving an error. Please help me with that. How do I get "player_name".

Comment: This would be so much easier if you use `Codable`.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Could you give me any example with my code?

Comment: No but you can use https://quicktype.io to help you get your structs set up and then read up on using `Codable` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types). There are also many other articles online and questions here to learn from.

Comment: @Jorn, notice that the sample data in the question is not in proper json format so most likely "team_id" is a string to start with and not an int.

Answer (score 0):

```
let playerArray:NSDictionary = json as! NSDictionary
for var player in playerArray {
    self.tryArray.append(player.objectForKey("player_name") as! String)
    self.tryArray.append(player.objectForKey("player_country") as! String)
}
```

Comment: Don't use NS classes, use proper swift types instead.

Comment: Please add some explanation for how this solves the problem. It's also super helpful when you can provide links which further document the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your response. I have tried this and it works.

```
var mainArray = NSArray()
var tryArray = [[String: Any]]()

    for i in jsonArray {
                        if i["team_key"] as! String == teamID {
                            self.mainArray = i["players"] as! NSArray
                        }
                    }

    for i in self.mainArray {
                    tryArray.append(i as! [String : Any])
                }
```

What I did was I made mainArray as NSArray instead of [[String: Any]] and then copy it to tryArray which is of actually [[String: Any]] type and used tryArray for my work.

Thanks.

Comment: While it may work for now I would still not force cast the JSON data. If you receive incorrectly formatted JSON data it could  still cause an exception. See my comment to the question for suggestion on how to do this the right way.